# Can't connect to remote mongodb with macOS

Tags: mongodb, macos, ssl, ibm-cloud

I am trying to connect to a mongodb service hosted on IBM Cloud following [this](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/databases-for-mongodb?topic=databases-for-mongodb-mongo-shell&locale=en-GB) instructions.

When I run the following command

```
mongo -u $USERNAME -p $PASSWORD --ssl --sslCAFile c5f07836-d94c-11e8-a2e9-62ec2ed68f84 --authenticationDatabase admin --host replset/bdb98a3ac10-0.b8a5e798d2d04f2e860d042c915.databases.appdomain.cloud:30484,bd576-96db98a3ac10-1.b8a5e4e5d042c915.databases.appdomain.cloud:30484
```

I get this error on macOs, while on Windows 10 the connection is correctly estiblished:

> SSL peer certificate validation failed: Certificate trust failure:
>   Invalid Extended Key Usage for policy; connection rejected

If I connect via MongoDB Compass instead of using the terminal the connection works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add `--sslAllowInvalidCertificates` flag

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.ssl.allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates